# Banco de dados, mostrar o nome através do ID

Tags: banco-de-dados, query

Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Tenha as seguintes tabelas

**JOGADORES**
id
nome
apelido
status

**EVENTOS**
id
data
local_id

**PLACARES**
id
evento_id
vencedor_id
perdedor_id

os campos vencedor_id e perdedor_id, guardam o id do jogador na tabela JOGADORES, como fazer uma consulta que retorno o nome do vencedor e o nome do perdedor?

Obrigado

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Se por algum motivo estiver faltando algum registro de jogador na tabela Placares, um LEFT JOIN poderá exibir todos os nomes, segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT 
    vencedor.nome AS vencedor, perdedor.nome AS perdedor
FROM
    placares pl
        LEFT JOIN
    jogadores vencedor ON vencedor.id = pl.vencedor_id
        LEFT JOIN
    jogadores perdedor ON perdedor.id = pl.perdedor_id;
```

Caso não seja necessário, um INNER JOIN será o suficiente.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT evt.data,
       venc.nome AS vencedor,
       perd.nome AS perdedor
  FROM placares p
       INNER JOIN eventos evt ON evt.id = p.evento_id
       INNER JOIN jogadores venc ON venc.id = p.vencedor_id
       INNER JOIN jogadores perd ON perd.id = p.perdedor_id
```

Utilizamos a cláusula `JOIN` para vincular duas tabelas. No caso acima utilizamos a coluna `vencedor_id` para vincular a tabela `jogadores` com a tabela `placares` e obter o nome do vencedor (`venc.nome`). Fazemos da mesma forma para encontrar o perdedor (`perdedor_id`).